# Business logic layer needs its own models or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, 3-tier

I'm doing 3 tier application using asp.net mvc and I want to do everything as recommended.

So I've done `MvcSample.Bll` for business logic, `MvcSample.Data` for data and `MvcSample.Web` for website.

In `Data` I've my `edmx` file (I'm using database first approach) and my repositories. And in `Bll` I'm doing services which will called in web.

So my question is that:
Should I write other models in `Bll` or use that ones which are generated in edmx file?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not use repositories with EF

Comment: *Should I write other models in Bll* That i assume you are talking about  entity class and not model.

Comment: you would face serialization issues (if you try to serialize any of the tables) with the references as some properties may be virtual and self referencing. 
Should be going with custom models.

Answer (score 1):

It heavily depends on the type of problem that your application is trying to solve.

From my experience, it is very rare that the business logic returns model objects directly from Entity Framework. Also, accepting these as arguments may not be the best idea.

Entity Framework model represents your relational database. Because of that, its definition contains many things that your business logic should not expose, for example navigation properties, computed properties etc. When accepting your model object as an argument, you may notice that many properties are not used by the particular business logic method. In many cases it confuses the developer and is the source of bugs.

All in all, if your application is a quick prototype, proof of concept or a simple CRUD software than it might be sufficient to use EF model classes. However, from practical point of view consider bespoke business logic model/dto classes.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you need another model for your `Bll`.

That would encapsulate your `Bll`completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no right or wrong answer for your question.

In my experience, I used both.
Let's see at below example:

I have an `User` table

```
 public class User
 {
     public int Id{get;set;}
     public string First_Name{get;set;}
     public string Last_Name{get;set;}
     public int Age{get;set;}
     public string Password{get;set;} //let's use this for demonstration 
 }
```

I have a Method call `DisplayAll()` in `Bll`. This method should list down all users in my database by Full Names (FirstName + LastName) and their Ages.
I should not return `User` class because it will expose the Password, but rather, I create a new Class `UserDto`

```
public class UserDto
{
    public string FullName{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

So here is my `DisplayAll()`:

```
public List<UserDto> DisplayAll()
{
    List<UserDto> result = ctx.User  //my DbContext
                  .Select(x => new UserDto()
                  {
                  FullName = x.First_Name + " " +Last_Name,
                  Age = x.Age
                  }
    return result;
}
```

So as you can see, my method `DisplayAll()` uses both `User` and `UserDto`

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be

```
MvcSample.Data
 -- Model Classes 
 -- EDMX attach to model
MvcSample.Bll
 -- Model Inheriting MvcSample.Data.Model
 -- Business Logic Class - Using MvcSample.Bll.Model
MvcSample.Web
 -- Controller using  MvcSample.Bll.Model
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your view about software design and how you want to take advantage of it. by separating BLL model, you will have your freedom to put story specific validation and calculation. By using only DLL model, it is sometimes tough as it is going to take effect in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 tier architecture in asp.net in this way

- `MvcSample.BLL` - business logic layer
- `MvcSample.DAL` - Data access layer
- `MvcSample.Domain` - Domain layer
- `MvcSample.web` - website

All your repository classes are including in `.BLL` layer.That means your logics are stored here.
Usually `.DAL` is used for storing `.edmx` classes. `.Domain` is using for recreate database objects that are useful for server side.That means if you are passing a `json` object from client to server,Then that object should be create on the server side.So those classes can be implement in the `.domain`